# Prove by induction that harmonic numbers have odd numerator and even denominator

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I was trying prove using induction principle that for all n > 1, P(n) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 +....+ 1/n = k/m
where k is an odd number and m is an even number. I tried proving first for n = 2, it holds. Then assuming
P(n), I tried proving P(n+1) , something like

1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 +...+ 1/n + 1/(n+1) = k/m + 1 / (n+1) ,
What I got after cross multiply was,
(k(n+1) + m)/((n+1)(m))
The denominator should be even here since m is even, but I am stuck here as I am unable to prove that numerator will be always odd. I don't really know how to move further or if my approach is correct at all. Please provide some idea as to how to go about these kinds of questions.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $k/m+1/(n+1)=\frac{a}{m(n+1)}$ where $a$ is some integer.

Comment: Sorry for not showing this step. This is my first question on this site. I did reach up until cross multiplication point, but I failed to somehow prove that the numerator will turn out to be odd for (n+1) being even. The denominator is trivially even.

Comment: So did you manage to prove the inductive step?

Comment: Sorry if I am not being much clear. Look, I just cross multiplied the terms and got an expression just as you mentioned and then I got stuck because I am unable to move ahead. The denominator seems to be even since m is even but how to prove that numerator will always be odd? I hope you got my doubt. I will edit the question to show what I got.

Comment: The denominator is not trivially even. Yes $m$ is even but it could cancel out with the numerator.

Comment: Yeah,I agree with that.Just now I noticed. So how to prove using induction? I just recently learnt it so I don't have much idea.

Comment: By the way, this is not a computer science topic, so i removed the tag.

Comment: I learnt both strong induction and simple induction while learning discrete mathematics for computer science yesterday only from MIT lecture notes. So I thought it might be a relevant tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H_n=\sum_{j=1}^n(1/j)=\frac {A_n}{B_n}$ in lowest terms.

Let $2^{f(n)}$ be the largest power of $2$ that divides $n.$ Let $2^{g(n)}$ be the largest power of $2$ that does not exceed $n.$ By looking at $H_n$ for some small $n,$ it seems that $f(B_n)=g(n).$ This is in fact is true for all $n.$

We have $3=A_2$ and $2=B_2$ and $1=f(B_2)=g(2).$

We show that if  $n\ge 2$ then $f(B_n)=g(n)\implies f(B_{n+1})=g(n+1).$

Suppose $n\ge 2$ and $f(B_n)=g(n).$

Then $A_n$ is odd. Because $B_n$ is divisible by the even number $2^{g(n)}=2^{f(B_n)}$ while $A_n/B_n$ is in lowest terms.

Let $B_n=C_n2^{f(B_n)}=C_n2^{g(n)}$ where $C_n$ is odd.

We have $$A_{n+1}/B_{n+1}=H_{n+1}=H_n+\frac {1}{n+1}=\frac {A_n}{C_n2^{g(n)}}+\frac {1}{n+1}=$$ $$=\frac {(n+1)A_n+2^{g(n)}C_n}{C_n2^{g(n)}(n+1)}. \quad (\bullet)$$

Case 1. If $n+1$ is odd: Then $g(n+1)=g(n)\ge 1$ so the numerator in $(\bullet)$ is odd while the denominator is the odd $C_n$ times  $2^{g(n)}=2^{g(n+1)}.$ So when $(\bullet)$ is reduced to lowest terms, the denominator must be an odd multiple of $2^{g(n+1)}.$

Case 2. If $n+1$ is even and $n+1$ is not a power of $2:$ Then $g(n+1)=g(n).$ Let $n+1=2^{f(n+1)}P$ where $P$ is odd. Now $2^{g(n+1)}<n+1< 2\cdot 2^{g(n+1)}$ so $f(n+1)<g(n+1)=g(n).$

The numerator in $(\bullet)$ is $$2^{f(n+1)}PA_n+2^{g(n)}C_n=2^{f(n+1)}Q$$ where $Q=PA_n+2^{g(n)-f(n+1)}C_n$ is odd.

And the denominator in $(\bullet)$ is $$C_n 2^{g(n)}2^{f(n+1)}P.$$ So  $(\bullet)$ can be partially reduced to $$\frac {Q}{C_n2^{g(n)}P}=\frac {Q}{C_n2^{g(n+1)}P}$$ with $Q, P,$ and $C_n$ odd.

Case 3. If $n+1$ is a power of $2.$ Then $n+1=2^{f(n+1)}=2^{g(n+1)}$ and $g(n+1)=1+g(n).$ So the numerator in $(\bullet)$ is $$2^{g(n+1)}A_n+2^{g(n)}C_n=2^{g(n)}R$$ where $R=2A_n+C_n$ is odd. And the denominator in $(\bullet)$ is $$C_n 2^{g(n)}2^{g(n+1)}.$$ So  $(\bullet)$ can be partially reduced to $$\frac {R}{C_n2^{g(n+1)}}$$ with $R$ and $C_n$ odd.

Comment: Wow man, Thanks a Lot!!!

Comment: Precisely what I wanted

Comment: This approach doesn't work if you want the highest power of $3$ that divides $B_n.$ And don't ask me. I dk.

Answer (score 3):

Plain induction as you are trying will not work, because you are trying to prove that $\frac{k(n+1)+m}{(n+1)m}$ simplifies to a fraction with odd numerator and even denominator, but the only information in the induction step is that $k$ is odd, $m$ is even and nothing about $n$. But letting $k=1$, $m=2$ and $n=5$ we get $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5+1} = \frac{2}{3}$ which shows that this information will not be enough to show what you want.

You'll need a stronger induction hypothesis (if you insists in proving this by induction).

Comment: My question still won't change. How to go about proving using strong induction?I did mention strong induction in the title.

Comment: As I said, you probably need an stronger induction HYPOTHESIS (that's not the same that using strong induction).

Comment: Understood.So, can you please help?If not the full answer,a small useful hint or perhaps point me in the right direction that could direct me towards the solution.As I said earlier, I just learnt this topic so I am out of ideas already.

Comment: I don't know how to do it using induction. I would use other methods.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway for letting me know that simple induction will not work here.I guess until I don't get an answer, I am gonna have to keep trying on my own.

Comment: I thing i find how to prove it by induction but seems a little artificial since it comes from other solution that don't use induction. Try proving that $H_n = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + \ldots + 1/n = a/(2^k b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are odd and $k = \lfloor \log_2 (n)\rfloor$.

Comment: I don't think this would be a suitable answer. I think that the intended solution is simpler than this.Although I wasn't able to figure it out